# Unable to get ID from the URL using useParams() Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I was trying to get ID from URL using `useParams()` hook, but it giving me error like below:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

I want to retrive the ID here - ProductDetails.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

function ProductDetails(props) {
  const { id } = useParams()
  const { setText } = props;
  console.log(id)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{id}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductDetails
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Header from './Components/Header';
import Homepage from './Components/HomePage';
import CartDetails from './Components/CartDetails';
import ProductDetails from './Components/ProductDetails';
import Error404 from './Components/Error404';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState(0);
 
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Header text={text}/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
          <Route exact path="/cart-details" component={()=> <CartDetails val={text} />} />
          <Route exact path="/products-details/:id" component={ProductDetails} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/products-details/:id"
            component={() => <ProductDetails setText={setText} />}
          />
          
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>

    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(

    <App />
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Is that the full `ProductDetails` component code? Why do you have two *nearly* identical routes? You don't pass a `setText` prop to the first one that will always be matched and rendered.

Comment: yeah, i have commented first one route in `app.js` but still same error

Comment: try commenting  the React import in  ProductDetails.jsx (first line)

Comment: Well, I don't see where you break any rules of hooks in these specific snippets. Have you verified the React/ReactDOM versions or that you aren't running 2 instances of React? I also suspect you're not sharing your entire `ProductDetails` component code either since your imports refer to other hooks and it seems overly simple. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: my package.json `"react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",`

Comment: in productsdetails.jsx component, i want to get the product ID that pushed from Homepage.jsx when use we click on the `<Link to={`/products-details/${itm.id}`}>VIEW DETAILS</Link>`.  will use that ID in productsdetails.jsx to display the complete details of that perticular product ID but i have not yet implemented whole code just trying to get its ID. thanks